# directory path search for :read

Tags: path

When I use `:read <filename>` in Vim, does it only look in the current working directory?

Is there a way to set up vim to have the `:read` read reference multiple directories when attempting to open a particular file?

Comment: You can give full path.it should work :)

Comment: If someone is looking for a convenient way to open files in vim's `'runtimepath'` directories, there is the plugin https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease which provides `:Vedit` for that. E.g. `:Vedit plugin/scriptease.vim` to open the actual plugins file. Otherwise this question sounds like the use case of `:find`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot configure the path that `:read` will use.  It will always start from the current directory. `:read` is not affected by the `path` variable in vim (see `:h path`). Although, see the workaround sections below.

Note that once you input `:read` into the prompt you can use <kbd>tab</kbd> for file and directory completion, including going up (with `..`) and down the directory tree.

---

#### Workaround 1: use `:find`

`:find` will open the file if it is present in any directory present in the `path` variable.  If you set the `path` as:

```
:set path=.,/home/me/myfiles
```

Then when you perform:

```
:find myfile
```

And `myfile` is not present in the working directory, vim will look for `/home/me/myfiles/myfile` and open it instead (if it exists).  You can have as many paths, separated by commas (`,`), in the `path` variable as needed.

`:h path` is very useful.

---

#### Workaround 2: script it

If you need the full functionality of `:read` (e.g. to add the contents of a file to another file), you can use the fact that `:read` can use the standard output of a command:

```
:read !<command>
```

Therefore you can write a script such as (I'm using `bash` here for brevity):

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/me/myfiles
cat $1
```

Let's say that the script is in the executable path (`PATH` on *nix, `%PATH%` on windows) and is called `myread.sh`, then you can perform:

```
:r !myread.sh myfile
```

To open `/home/me/myfiles/myfile` from *any* working directory.